# Control access to methods in base class, inherited from interface

Tags: c#

I have a basic design consisting of the following classes and interfaces:

- a `IRepository<TEntity>` interface,
- a `Repository<TEntity>` base class,
- and a concrete `TenantRepository` class.

### The "problem"

Since everything inherited by the interface has public access by definition, I am allowed to call the `Add` method (base class)

```
_tenantRepository.Add(new Tenant { Name = "blah" } );
```

while I should be calling the `Create` method on `TenantRepository`

```
_tenantRepository.Create("blah");
```

### The question

It would be nice if I was able to define the `Add` method as protected so that client code could not access the method, but that's not allowed due to the simple fact that it's a method defined in the interface and must have public access.

Alternatively I *could* name the methods identical so that I actually override the implementation in the concrete class. That would prevent the client code from calling the `Repository.Add` directly. But in some cases I really want to prevent client code from calling the method defined in the base class.

Another alternative could be to write something like this:

```
    new protected void Add(Tenant tenant)
    {

    }
```

but that makes me shiver (and it will break soon enough when I start refactoring method names).

**Is there a better way to achieve this?**

---

### Some code snippets as reference:

The interface:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : IEntity
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void Add(TEntity entity);
}
```

A small portion of the base class:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    protected IDbContext Context;

    public Repository(IDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    // Left out other, for this question irrelevant, method implementations 
}
```

And finally the `TenantRepository`

```
public class TenantRepository : Repository<Tenant>
{
    public TenantRepository(IDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public Tenant Create(string tenantName)
    {
        var tenant = new Tenant
            {
                Name = tenantName,
                Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            };

        if (Exists(tenant.Name))
        {
            throw new TenantAlreadyExistsException(tenant.Name);
        }

        Add(tenant);

        return tenant;
    }

    // Left out other, for this question irrelevant, method implementations 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just make `Add` `virtual` in your `Repository` base class (or inherit directly from the `IRepository`, without using the base class at all)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to make TenantRepository not inherit from your Repository. After all, it sounds like they have different functionality (you want to have Create instead of Add.)

If you go this route, Repository becomes a private member of your TenenantRepository class, as only it would know what repository methods should be called when.

Comment: I think you provided the best solution. Going for an explicit interface implementation would leave me with code like this: `IRepository<CaseType> repo = this;` in order to call `repo.Add(caseType);`. That is exactly why you propose an association instead isn't it?

Comment: You have quite an eye. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I indeed created a design flaw, and by associating the repository I already found another bug. +1 thx a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped. Sometimes we get so caught up in going forward with our design that we need someone from the outside to take a look. It's happened to me countless times.

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the Add method using [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Basically, in Repository, do this:

```
public IRepository<Tenant>.Add(Tenant toAdd)
{
    //do the add
}
```

This they can only get by casting to an IRepository.

Comment: Ahhhh that's something I never used before. Sounds like a winner. I'll give it a try

Comment: thx for the proposal, I tried this approach but the actual problem was a bit below the surface. taylonr pointed that out to me. +1 for the idea tho. Now I also know when to use explicit interfaces! :)

Answer (score 0):

if in a `TenantRepository` you need `Add` to check for uniqueness of the `Tenant`, you should include that logic within the `Add` method itself.
You should make `Add` in your base `Repository` class `virtual` and `override` it in your TenantRepository so that it performs the uniqueness check you now have in your `Create` method.

```
public interface IRepository<T> 
{
    void Add(T entity);
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> 
{
    // mocking Add so it works without a DB
    public virtual void Add(T entity) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} added", entity.ToString());
    }
}

public class Tenant 
{
    public string Name{get; private set;}
    public Tenant(string Name)
    {
        this.Name=Name;
    }

    public override string ToString() {return this.Name;}

}

public class TenantRepository : Repository<Tenant>
{
    // Add is virtual, so it can be overridden by TenantRepository
    public override void Add(Tenant entity)
    {
        // this represents your uniqueness check
        if(entity.Name=="Paolo") throw new Exception();

        base.Add(entity); // calling Add on the base Repository
    }

    //you can now avoid having Create or making it just call Add
    public Tenant Create(Tenant entity) 
    {
        this.Add(entity);
        return entity;
    }
}
```